# Automatically selecting the best of several estimators in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

Does scikit-learn have an estimator that runs several other estimators and automatically selects the one with the best performance (e.g. according to their cross-validation scores)?

I believe there must be something like this in a class that conforms to the estimator interface, so that it can be combined in a [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html) - correct?

Comment: I think you mean an ensemble method http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html ? But Im confused by your question. Cross_validation is derived by aggregate examples, so selecting the best based on cross_validation error would be something you would do in preprocessing and testing if you are ultimately going to select one best classifier. If that's not what you after, can you clarify the question?

Comment: Usually I would test the performance of different estimators using cross-validation. Then I would manually select the best-performing for the final predictions. Now I want to implement my entire workflow using sklearn pipelines, so this final step needs to be performed by one class implementing the estimator interface, too, I believe. I don't believe that "ensemble methods" is the right answer - predictions should not be combined.

Comment: IMO, scikit doesnt contain anything like what you want. But You can take hints from here : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-classification-plot-classifier-comparison-py

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scikit-learn itself currently doesn't have what you are looking for. However, there are libraries like [TPOT](https://github.com/rhiever/tpot) and [automl-learn](https://github.com/automl/auto-sklearn) with sklearn-like interface for automatic selection of best estimator or even constructing the whole pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It is surprising that sklearn does not have it - I believe this is a straightforward step that is performed very often in ML workflows.

Answer (score 8):

You can use GridSearchCV, not only to choose the best estimator but also to tune its hyperparameters, for example, I'm using this for finding the best text classifier:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2))),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=True)),
    ('clf', SVC())
])

parameters = {'clf': [
    SVC(),
    MultinomialNB(),
    BernoulliNB(),
    MLPClassifier(max_iter=1000),
    KNeighborsClassifier(),
    SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000),
    RandomForestClassifier()
]}

gs_clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
gs_clf = gs_clf.fit(X, y)

print("Best score", gs_clf.best_score_)

for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
    print("%s: %r" % (param_name, gs_clf.best_params_[param_name]))
```

Example from the official docs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-compare-reduction-py

You can even define your own scoring function, to define what "best" means to you:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter